# Send message using JMS and ApacheMQ and spring boot

Tags: java, spring, maven

Hi I want to send message to `Active MQ`. I am using Spring Boot with apache MQ. I don't want to use any xml class so I have defined beans in `Configuration.java` class and  those beans I want to use in MessageSenderClass. How can i use it?

I have three classes:

1..SenderApplication

```
package com.ge.Controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsMessagingTemplate;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SenderApplication {
    /*@Autowired
    JmsMessageSender jmsmessagingSender;*/

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SenderApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

2.. SendingMessageController

```
package com.ge.Controller;

import javax.jms.JMSException;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@Controller
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class SendingMessageController {

    @Autowired
    MessageSenderClass msgSenderClass;

@RequestMapping(value="/sending",method= {RequestMethod.POST})
@ResponseBody
public String greeting() 
{

    String msg="Welcome to GE";
    System.out.println("MESSAGE-1");
    try {
        msgSenderClass.onDataLoadMessage(msg);
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ("Welcome to GE");
    }   

}
```

3..MessageSenderClass

```
package com.ge.Controller;
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection;
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageProducer;
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession;
import org.apache.activemq.spring.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListener;
import org.springframework.jms.support.destination.DestinationResolver;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.ge.config.AppConfig;
@Component
public class MessageSenderClass 
{

    private ActiveMQMessageProducer messageProducer=null;
private ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory=null;

@Autowired
ActiveMQConnection connection;
private ActiveMQSession session=null;

private Destination destination = null;
/*@Autowired
DestinationResolver destinationResolver;*/


    @JmsListener(destination = "dataLoadChannel")
    public void onDataLoadMessage(String message) throws JMSException
    {
        System.out.println("M in on load data method");
        System.out.println(message);
         connection = (ActiveMQConnection) activeMQConnectionFactory.createConnection();

          connection.start();

                     session = (ActiveMQSession) connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

                     destination =session.createQueue("SAMPLEQUEUE");
                     messageProducer = (ActiveMQMessageProducer) session.createProducer(destination);

                     TextMessage message1 = session.createTextMessage();

                                 message1.setText("Hello ...This is a sample message..sending from FirstClient");
                     messageProducer.send(message1);

                     System.out.println("Sent: " + message1.getText());



    }


}
```

4.ApplicationConfig

```
package com.ge.config;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.Session;

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession;
import org.apache.activemq.RedeliveryPolicy;
import org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.EnableJms;
import org.springframework.jms.config.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.support.destination.BeanFactoryDestinationResolver;
import org.springframework.jms.support.destination.DestinationResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class AppConfig {

    @Resource
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Resource
    private Settings settings;

    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {

       DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
       factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
       factory.setDestinationResolver(destinationResolver());
       factory.setConcurrency("9");
       factory.setTransactionManager(null);

       return factory;
    }


    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {

       ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(settings.getActiveMQBrokerUrl());

       RedeliveryPolicy policy = new RedeliveryPolicy();
       policy.setMaximumRedeliveries(0);
       activeMQConnectionFactory.setRedeliveryPolicy(policy);

       return activeMQConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DestinationResolver destinationResolver() {
        return new BeanFactoryDestinationResolver(applicationContext);
    }

    @Bean
    public ActiveMQQueue dataLoadChannel()
    {
       return new ActiveMQQueue(settings.getDataLoadDestination());
    }
}
```

Maven pom.xml:

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>MainJMSTemplate</groupId>
  <artifactId>MainJMSTemplate</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <properties>    
    <!-- Spring version -->
    <spring-framework.version>4.1.0.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>    
    <!-- ActiveMQ version -->
    <activemq.version>5.10.0</activemq.version>
  </properties>


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>



    <!-- Spring aritifacts -->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>  

    <!-- ActiveMQ Artifacts -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
      <artifactId>activemq-spring</artifactId>
      <version>${activemq.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies> 

  <!-- Using JDK 1.7 for compiling -->
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <!-- <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories> -->

</project>
```

In `AppConfig` file M defining beans and those beans i want to use in MessageSenderClass How can i use it?

Comment: What is the question/error here? What stops you importing/autowiring those beans?

Comment: I dont know how to do it if m writing  @Autowired
  ConnectionFactory factory;  in MessageSender Class. It is sshowing this error  Error creating bean with name 'messageSenderClass': Injection of autowired dependencies failed

Comment: I think you should re-read the documentation because you got some things completely backwards. `@JmsListener` will automatically provide you a listener so a) you never invoke the method yourself, b) all the business to send something has nothing to do there.